# Problem: bocce balls put into a box.

Tags: calculus

In  $ \mathbb {R}^3 $, there is a unit cube centered at the origin (each of its side is of length 1).

Eight bocce (bocci ?) balls are put into the cube. They are centered at $$ \left(\pm \frac {1}{4} ; \pm \frac {1}{4} ; \pm \frac {1}{4} \right) $$

Each ball is tangent to 3 sides of the box, and to 3 other balls.

The jack is put in the centre of the box. Find the biggest (maximal) value of the radius of the jack.

It is said that the balls and the jack can bee seen as spheres.

I don't know how to solve this. Thanks for your help !

Comment: *bocce* is already plural: the Italian singular would be *boccia*, which is also the name of a slightly [different game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boccia).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

......................................

Answer (score 1):

The corners of the box are at $(\pm 1/2, \pm 1/2, \pm 1/2)$, so the balls have radius $1/4$. The closest point of each ball to the origin lies on a line from the origin to each ball's center. The line from the origin to the center of the ball in the first octant is $x = y = z$ (the other octants are symmetrical). The point on this line a distance $1/4$ away from $(1/4, 1/4, 1/4)$ in the direction of the origin is $(r, r, r)$ where $r = \frac{1}{4} - \frac{1}{4 \sqrt{3}} $ is the radius of the jack.